# Java использование Properties глобально

Tags: java

Как правильно использовать `java.util.Properties` в приложении? Важны такие требования:

- Конфиг должен быть доступен с диска для редактирования, а не быть в .jar
- Приложение запускается под кроном, поэтому надо избежать проблем с абсолютными путями
- Конфиг должен быть доступен во многих классах программы

Насчет последнего пункта, как это можно сделать? Использовать синглтон?

```
package properties;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final String configPath = "src/main/resources/config.properties";
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.load(new FileInputStream(configPath));
        System.out.println(props.getProperty("mode"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеку http://owner.aeonbits.org/. По последнему пункту можно использовать dependency injection

Comment: @Maxim, по-моему, это каргокультизм, когда вместо Properties используют целую библиотеку и DI

Comment: передавайте путь к конфигу как параметр командной строки, переменную окружения или ищите его в домашнем каталоге пользователя, `/etc/вашеприложение` или другом заранее оговоренном месте

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно разместить properties файл рядом с jar, можно использовать такой код

```
Properties props = new Properties();
// Получаем путь к jar
URI uri = MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI();
// Получаем каталог jar файла
String path = new File(uri).getParent();
log.debug(() -> "Load properties from " + path);
// Загружаем конфиг
try (InputStream file = new FileInputStream(path + "/connection.properties")) {
    props.load(file);
}
```

Но очень часто у обычного пользователя не будет прав на редактирование файлов в этом каталоге. Если такое поведение не устраивает, то можно разместить properties файл в домашнем каталоге пользователя. Путь к каталогу можно получить так

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Answer (score 0):

По поводу доступности везде. Есть достаточно хорошая реализация расширителя `Properties()`.

Код ExProperty.java

```
public class ExProperties extends Properties
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void load(final String fileName) throws IOException
    {
        load(new File(fileName));
    }

    public void load(final File file) throws IOException
    {
        try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file))
        {
            load(is);
        }
    }

    public boolean getBoolean(final String name, final boolean defaultValue)
    {
        boolean val = defaultValue;

        final String value;

        if ((value = super.getProperty(name, null)) != null)
            val = Boolean.parseBoolean(value);

        return val;
    }

    public String getString(final String name, final String defaultValue)
    {
        String val = defaultValue;

        final String value;

        if ((value = super.getProperty(name, null)) != null)
            return value;

        return val;
    }

    public int getInteger(final String name, final int defaultValue)
    {
        int val = defaultValue;

        final String value;

        if ((value = super.getProperty(name, null)) != null)
            val = Integer.parseInt(value);

        return val;
    }

    public long getLong(final String name, final long defaultValue)
    {
        long val = defaultValue;

        final String value;

        if ((value = super.getProperty(name, null)) != null)
            val = Long.parseLong(value);

        return val;
    }

    public double getDouble(final String name, final double defaultValue)
    {
        double val = defaultValue;

        final String value;

        if ((value = super.getProperty(name, null)) != null)
            val = Double.parseDouble(value);

        return val;
    }
}
```

Код Prop.java

```
public final class Prop
{
    public static ExProperties _properties;

    public static int TEST_INTEGER;
    public static long TEST_LONG;

    public static final void load()
    {
        _properties = initProperties("filename.properties");

        TEST_INTEGER = _properties.getInteger("testInteget", -1);
        TEST_LONG = _properties.getLong("testLong", -1L);
    }

    public static final ExProperties getProperties()
    {
        return _properties;
    }

    public static final ExProperties initProperties(String filename)
    {
        final ExProperties result = new ExProperties();

        try
        {
            result.load(new File(filename));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("An error occured loading '" + filename + "' properties.");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Варианты использования:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Prop.load();

        final int testInt_1 = Prop.TEST_INTEGER;
        final int testInt_2 = Prop.getProperties().getInteger("testInteger", -1);
    }
}
```

Если файл с конфигурацией будет лежать рядом с исполняемым файлом, то не вижу смысла указывать пути через вычисление местоположение исполняемого файла. Можно просто указать где искать относительно JAR.

```
_properties = initProperties("./Properties.properties");
```

Comment: Он будет искать относительно **текущего** каталога. Проверьте `java -jar prog/myprog.jar`